# tuple identity when calling tuple on a tuple

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals

I was hypothesizing that `tuple(tuple_instance)` should (as an optimization) be able to return the input tuple without making a copy.  It turns out that on CPython this *appears* to be the case:

```
>>> t = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
>>> v = tuple(t)
>>> v is t
True
```

good so far.  However, perusing the source, I see that there is [PyTuple_MAXSAVESIZE](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3852afce2ca3/Objects/tupleobject.c#l7) which *could* be coming in to play here.  Lets try it for bigger tuples:

```
>>> t = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz') * 100
>>> v = tuple(t)
>>> v is t
True
```

And that seems to work too.

My main question is whether or not this behavior is always the case in CPython.  I looked at [PyTuple_New](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3852afce2ca3/Objects/tupleobject.c#l65), but I can't see anything in there that would explain what I'm seeing here, so this behavior must be defined somewhere else (or I missed it... my C is pretty atrophied at this point...).

Comment: Few moments @mglison actually asks a question :) +1

Comment: [`tuple_new`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/55fed3eae14b/Objects/tupleobject.c#l644) is what's called when you do `tuple(t)`, and that ends up calling `PySequence_Tuple` on the argument. `PySequence_Tuple` probably returns its argument if the argument is a tuple, but I can't find the source for that function.

Comment: This looks like the source for `PySequence_Tuple`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/10dccd220ea2f45bd4b7eba3d7766d7c0a4646ad/Objects/abstract.c#L1660

Comment: It's in [`abstract.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3852afce2ca3/Objects/abstract.c#l1660)  (YaY grep!).  That ends up calling PyTuple_CheckExact which is actually a [macro](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3852afce2ca3/Include/tupleobject.h#l41)...

Comment: @ToClickorNottoClick -- It turns out I've asked 107 :-).  A number of them are tick-tack stuff like this where I'm mostly curious about python implementation/details.  A few are about matplotlib (because that package is crazy...).  A few about the depths of numpy... Frequently it's optimization stuff cuz I find it interesting...

Comment: Anyway, all of your questions make me think... I'm glad for that

Comment: @user2357112 -- Thanks for the pointer to `tuple_new`.  That (plus grep) were enough for me to track down the whole call sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so the call sequence is:

[tuple_new](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3852afce2ca3/Include/tupleobject.h#l41) calls PySequence_Tuple at the end.  [PySequence_Tuple](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/55fed3eae14b/Objects/abstract.c#l2152) has the optimization built in that if it's a tuple (not a tuple subclass), it just returns the tuple  (See the line with `PyTuple_CheckExact` which is actually a [macro](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3852afce2ca3/Include/tupleobject.h#l41)...)

SO, in summary, currently (CPython2.7.7) calling `tuple` on an instance of `tuple` will return the input instance *iff* the input tuple's type *is* `tuple`.  Subclasses of `tuple` will get copied.

There is also appears to be an optimized path for lists as well.  This might cover `tuple` subclasses as well, but I didn't dig that far.